# How to find integer array length when array passed to another function from main?

Tags: c

How can I get arrayLength from user defined function?

```
int getArrayLength(int *arr){
   //our logic
   return result;
}
```

Comment: One way you could deterimine the length is to set the last element to a delimiter value like 0, or pass in the size along with arr. The first method is unrecommended though.

Comment: This might be the time to consider switching to a higher level language

Comment: down voting simply because a question is a duplicate is overkill, especially when 1) the OP is new to SO.  2) the question is clearly and succinctly asked.

Answer (score 3):

Simply: you cannot. You should pass it as another argument:

```
int getArrayLength(int *arr, int size){ ...
```

If you try with sizeof, it will return the size of the pointer. You can also use a special value to indicate the last element of your array (like 0 for strings), but adding a convention can make things more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to do one of two things:

1. Have the caller provide the length, or...
2. Agree on a sentinel value that lets you detect the end of the array.

In the general case, the right answer is option 1. You shouldn't write functions that take C arrays without also taking a length parameter.

In some specific cases, option 2 works pretty well. For example, `\0` is used to mark the end of strings, which are just character arrays. If `0` isn't a valid value for the elements of array, that could work for cases other than strings. But generally, go with option 1.

Comment: Presented concepts _similar_ to, but improved over other answers, and well stated, with good supporting reasons.  Like that you validated use of sentinel values. +1

Answer (score 2):

Pass array length to the function too otherwise you can't. This is because `sizeof(arr)` will give you size of the pointer to `int`, not the size of entire array.